# Haskell converting [Char] to Char

Tags: haskell, type-systems

I'm working on a Haskell program that uses whte `Network.Wai` and `Network.Socket.Internal` modules. In this program, I have a function, defined like so:

```
prepareIp :: Request -> [([Char], [Char])]
prepareIp req = [("Remote", head $ splitOn ":" $ show $ remoteHost req)]
```

Originally, I made this a monadic expression (mostly for readability and clarity), written:

```
prepareIp :: Request -> [([Char], [Char])]
prepareIp req = do
     ip <- head $ splitOn ":" $ show $ remoteHost req
     [("Remote", ip)]
```

While the former implementation does work properly, the monadic one threw an error I can't wrap my head around: its output type was not `[([Char], [Char])]`, but `[([Char], Char)]` -- the value `ip` was, for some reason, being turned into a single character rather than a string!

I also tried prototyping this in GHCi and type-checking using the module references as well as `:t` in GHCi, but to no avail, and I still don't know what caused this error.

Can anyone clue me in on why this type conflict is happening?

Comment: Why are you returning a list in the first place, looks like you'd be better off with `Request -> (String, String)` (`String` is just an alias for `[Char]`), then just have `prepareIp req = ("Remote", head $ splitOn ":" $ show $ remoteHost req)`, and if that's not readable enough for you, then use a local `let`, such as `prepareIp req = let ip = head $ splitOn ":" $ show $ remoteHost req in ("Remote", ip)`, although with more whitespace mixed in to make it easy to read.

Comment: You also probably should be pattern matching on the `SockAddr` returned by `remoteHost req` to extract the IP (as a `HostAddress` or `HostAddress6`), rather than converting it to a string to slice and dice.

Comment: As for why it thought you needed `Char` and not a `[Char]`, it's because when you have `ip <-`, it extracts each element from the list on the right side of the `<-`, and since in this case `head` returns a `String`, which is equivalent to `[Char]`, the compiler expects `ip` to have the type `Char`.  You really just need a `let` here, not monads.

Comment: @bheklilr I didn't know pattern matching on a `Word32` was possible (since that's all a `HostAddress` is -- how could this be done?

Comment: You would pattern match on the constructors of `SockAddr`, not on `Word32` itself: `case remoteHost req of { SockAddrInet port addr -> ...; SockAddrInet6 port flow addr6 scope -> ...; SockAddrUnix addr -> ...}`.

Comment: And thanks for the answer! That does make sense. You could make that an answer instead of keeping it in the comments.

Comment: Awesome. I'm still new to pattern matching, it isn't always obvious what can be pattern-matched on and how.

Comment: Now it's giving me a strange versioning issue - apparently the `case of` block produces a `network-2.6.1.0:Network.Socket.Types.SockAddr` out of `remoteHost req`, while matching against `SockAddrInet port addr` (etc) needs a `network-2.6.0.2:Network.Socket.Types.SockAddr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing that error is because you're trying to shove everything into a monad when it doesn't need to be.  To illustrate, adding explicit type signatures everywhere and swapping `[]` for `m`:

```
getHostIp :: Request -> m []
getHostIp req = head $ splitOn ":" $ remoteHost req

prepareIp :: Request -> m ([Char], [Char])
prepareIp req = do
    ip <- (getHostIp req :: m Char)
    [("Remote" :: [Char], ip :: [Char])]
```

Whenever you see `<-`, the right side has to have some type like `m a` where `m` is some monadic type and `a` is whatever the result of that monadic action is.  Then, then left side of the `<-` has type `a`.  Here you've used `<-` to try to get the value out of a `[Char]`, when you really just want the value of that `[Char]` completely.  A `let` is appropriate here, and `do` notation is superfluous.  Since you're also returning only a single value, I'd recommend just returning `(String, String)` instead of `[(String, String)]`:

```
prepareIp :: Request -> (String, String)
prepareIp req =
    let ip = getHostIp req
    in ("Remote", ip)
```